# "Method expression is not of Function type" warning in WebStorm

Tags: redux, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

WebStorm is warning me for `dispatch` variable `Method expression is not of Function type` in code below. I'm using JS, not TS. All dependencies are OK. Everything works well, but this warning is a little bit annoying.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const toggleDirIsOpen = () => dispatch(toggleIsDirOpen(dictionaryCategoryId));
```

[image]

Can anyone tell, what's the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the IDE resolves the `dispatch` type as `Dispatch<any>` - seems this is not a function, thus the warning. It;'s either a problem with the IDE or an issue with typings (`d.ts` files) of a library being used